# Operation on two GEOMETRIES with different SRIDs

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.2

Hi I'm trying to get all the points that are within 10km of a certain point but I keep getting

> ERROR: Operation on two GEOMETRIES with different SRIDs

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM milllocations_30aug2014 WHERE st_distance(milllocations_30aug2014.shape, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-93.62011857184822 51.02535700166606)', 4269))< 10000
```

also milllocations_30aug2014.shape is something like this : 0101000020E61000007CF9F5285CAF5DC088DE3D0AD7834B40

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it using st_transform

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " + areaTable.getValue() + " WHERE st_distance(ST_Transform("+areaTable.getValue()+".shape,4269), ST_GeomFromText('POINT("+longitude+" "+latitude+")', 4269))< 10000
```

Comment: You might get better performance if you set the SRID of you table first, rather than transforming on the fly like this.